# Oh Gun Bro, Wherefore art thou so bad?

Tags: gun-bros

I'm playing Gun Bros and I'm nearly at the end of the first stage, but while I'm rocking an awesome gun, my bro seems stuck with some pea shooter.

[image: Yes I own the quaduple gun! My bro's a sissy...]

So this leaves me wondering, can I somehow upgrade my bro or does he upgrade automatically when you reach the next stage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your default bro will not upgrade to better weapons, armors or higher number of hitpoints. However, you can connect via GameCenter to other players and use their bros, with upgraded weapons and armors. The game gets pretty hard without using other players' bros.

You can find other Gun Bros players [here](http://www.facebook.com/topic.php?uid=131938276841442&topic=385), as an example.

Comment: the Facebook link is expired